# How to add total cart weight to invoice in opencart?

Tags: php, opencart, invoice

i am developing an ecommerce website on opencart 1.5.6. site is almost ready but i stuck on 1 point.
for example i have 4 product in my cart with weight 100gram each. I already add the weight column in invoice for each product. but now i want to show the total weight of cart or the sum of the all products weight.
 i got the ref. for adding weight from here : 
http://www.opencartaz.com/opencart/-vqmod-add-weight-to-invoice.html

Here is the screenshot attached.

[image]

please help me.

Comment: It would be helpful to show what you have already or a specific point where you want to run the code with your input variables

Comment: but how to get total weight into the invoice template.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using vqmod?

Search in the file `admin/view/template/sale/order_invoice.tpl` for `<?php foreach ($order['voucher'] as $voucher) { ?>`.

Set the position to before and add:

```
<tr>
  <td align="right" colspan="4"><b>Total Weight:</b></td>
  <td align="right"><?php 
    $total_weight = 0;
    foreach($order['product'] as $product) {
      $total_weight += $product['weight'];
    }
    echo $total_weight;
  ?></td>
  <td> </td>
</tr>
```

This will add the total product weight between the list of products and the vouchers.

Comment: i used this code but it shows only 0kg weight. you can see the screenshot above.

Comment: @ Richard Parnaby-King Thank you. it works. i modifiy it accoring to product quantity.